# Are Visual Studio Questions On Topic?

Tags: discussion

So I have a question about tabs in Visual Studio 2013, and I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254005/let-visual-studio-2012-2013-open-files-to-the-right-instead-of-to-the-left)(and there's other similar examples)(also, my sincere apologies if linking to that question gets it closed or something) which is similar to what I want to ask. However, still not quite sure if Visual Studio questions are on topic since it's arguably a question about using a specific software, and it can be argued that such a question may belong on Super User.

Still, I'd figure programmers would be the people to ask about Visual Studio (not sure if Programmers would be a better fit for such questions).

When in doubt, ask Meta? So, are Visual Studio questions on topic? If it's a grey area, what type of Visual Studio questions are allowed?

For reference, I want to ask about tab order. When I have a lot of files open and the tabs spill over into that expandable list, clicking an already open file opens the tab on the right. This is exceedingly annoying as the ones on the left are the files I consider to be the ones I'm working on, and the ones on the right are older. But if I open more than one file, it hides files on the left and opens the newer tabs on the right. I was hoping there's a setting to use the old 2010 behavior of opening existing files on the left and hiding the tabs on the far right.

Comment: Visual Studio questions are absolutely on-topic, yes.

Comment: Hmm ... If that's the answer then I guess I can try asking my question. I'll wait a bit to see if this question gets any other answers

Comment: It's right in the Help Center. I'm on mobile, but just go look yourself. As long as it's a quality question, and is a tool primarily used by developers, it's on topic.

Comment: Well, don't know why I didn't try the help center first :/ "My bad" as the kids say

Comment: :) hope my short typing above didn't come across as abrupt, btw! Wasn't intended to be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Visual Studio is absolutely ["a tool commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers; and is**
> - **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**

Although questions to recommend a plugin for VS would be off-topic. However, as your question is clearly not about a tool recommendation, it would be a perfect question for Stack Overflow.