# Why was this question about IIS and Visual Studio migrated to Stack Overflow from Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

Today I asked the following question on Server Fault:

[Is there a way to publish a site from Visual Studio to an IIS without admin rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281910/is-there-a-way-to-publish-a-site-from-visual-studio-to-an-iis-without-admin-righ)

I was pretty sure it's about IIS administration or some *mysterious* system settings, but now I see it was moved to Stack Overflow where it will most likely get closed for being off-topic. (I would flag it off-topic myself if I stumbled upon it).

I'm really confused by the question getting migrated.

Where should I acutually have asked it?

Comment: This is probably better on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) where there's the [site-recommandation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag for this.

Comment: @KevinBrown, ok, thank you... I didn't know that yet... I'll move it.

Comment: @KevinBrown there is a [site-recommendation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag here, though I've asked to get [rid of it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261454/clean-up-the-site-recomendations-meta-tag).

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite the title...

Comment: This might be why it was migrated: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269249/are-visual-studio-questions-on-topic?rq=1

Comment: So there is virtualy no way to ask a question concerning IIS on severfault if Visual Studio is involved... even if it might be a pure administration matter :(

Comment: The use of Visual Studio seems like a red herring in this question.  The question is asking how to allow a non-administrative user to have permission to publish to an IIS site.  That the request is made through VS instead of directly to IIS seems like it shouldn't matter.

Comment: ...but if I ask it without mentioning Visual Studio someone probably will ask for more information like why I need it or what I am going to achieve... then I say about publishing from Visual Studio and few minutes later the question is most probably on Stack Overflow again :( it's a vicious circle and a paradox.

Comment: @MichaelHampton maybe you could clarify what did I do wrong or how should I have asked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the question have been moved? Eh... yeah, maybe-probably. It involves Visual Studio, which is more a developer tool than a sysadmin tool.

You'll be happy to know, though, that **the question *is* on-topic for SO** because it *directly involve[s] programming or programming tools**.

*From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

> 6. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: An answer after almost four years! Thanks! ;-) at the same time I'm a little bit embarassed that I didn't know what was on-topic... but it's not that bad as apperently most regulars wern't able to answer it for the last four years either.

Comment: Answer a 3 1/2 years old question and have the answer accepted in 3 minutes... Meta is weird.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ You dig up some old questions when you browse by tag.

Comment: It's not a task "unique to software development". The programmer doesn't have any say on how IIS publish a site, the system administrator does.

Comment: @Braiam No? When else do you use Visual Studio to publish a website to IIS? Of course it's unique to software development. Visual Studio is an Integrated _Development_ Environment. Further, the question states, "without admin rights", so clearly not a sysadmin.

Comment: I use Visual Studio to compile a version of MariaDB. Am I developing software? No, I didn't even write a single line of code. The topicality of a question isn't determined by the tools used, but by the task being asked about.

Comment: That seems to contradict the quote in the answer. "... or programming tools."

Comment: @JakeReece because the quote is incomplete. "software tools commonly used by programmers; **and** is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" It needs both conditions to be true, not just one.